# language packs on windows : winapi

Tags: windows, winapi, language-packs

how to retrieve all available language packs to set it to current thread language to use in FormateMessage afterward? I need exactly languages which may be used to use in function SetThreadUILanguage. After that I need to use FormateMessage function, which will extract message as current thread's one.

Comment: They require the Ultimate edition, are half a gigabyte each and need to be downloaded and installed.  They'll show up as available updates in Windows Update.  Nothing you do programmatically.

Comment: @Hans, I suppose that system message are translated into system (installation) language. Thus, any UI language I download via Windows Update will have translations for GUI, but not system messages table. What is your sight?